# Is there a module that can create a Taxonomy out of the installed modules?

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, feeds, importing-exporting, configuration

Is there a module that can create a Taxonomy out of the installed modules?

I want to create simple configuration tracking system and need to make my modules one of the taxonomies.

In relation to existing configuration management systems I got a suggestion here [Is there a module for tracking changes to a Drupal site's configuration?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/88747/is-there-a-module-for-tracking-changes-to-a-drupal-sites-configuration) so any other existing options for configuraton management should be answered there.

Answer (score 0):

I have decided to use a combination of 3 modules to accomplish the task.

[Views System](https://drupal.org/project/views_system), [Views Data Export](https://drupal.org/project/views_data_export) and [Taxonomy import/export via XML](https://drupal.org/project/taxonomy_xml)

`Views System` is a Views module that lists all the installed modules and themes. `Views Data Export` enables the output of `Views System` to be exported as XML or CSV which `Taxonomy import/export via XML` can then import into a taxonomy.

A module which can update taxonomies from feeds would be nice, there is probably a module for that, but these will do for the time being.